# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when sending Json with Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax

I'm using the [ajax-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajax-request) package to send Json data via a post request in my Node.js application. The relevant code snippet looks like this:

```
logMessage : function(url, message, next) {
  var d1 = message["sender"];
  var d2 = { id: message[sender"]["id"], name: message["sender"]["name"], email: message["sender"]["email"] };
  console.log(d1); // Both outputs look 
  console.log(d2); // exactly the same
  request.post({ url: url, headers: {}, data: d1 }, function (error, response, body) {
    //Check for error
    if(error){
      next(null, {}); // I'm not worried if the logging fails
    }
    //Check for right status code
    if(response.statusCode !== 200){
      next(null, {}); // I'm not worried if the logging fails
    }
    next(null, {})    // All good
  });
}
```

The problem is that I get a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. The `message` object definitely doesn't contain any circular references, and the `message` is neither that large nor that nested. The call works fine when I use dummy data or drill down to a basic data type, i.e., the following works fine

- `data: { 'test': [1, 2, 3]}`
- `data: message['sender']['name']` <-- this is a string value
- `data: message['sender']['email']` <-- this is a string value

However, `data: message['sender']` already fails although it only contains an object with two simple strings.

The workaround `data: JSON.stringify(message)` would work, but I still like to understand what the issue is.

**EDIT:** I've added `d1` and `d2` as to objects that should be the same, and the `console.log` outputs are look indeed exactly the same. However, `data: d2` is working, while `data: d1` is not

**EDIT2:** `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(message))` as another workaround does the job as well. I guess my `message` object is not what I thought it would be.

Comment: There must be something else happening. Is this request being sent repeatedly? Is the return handler triggering another action?

Comment: I've edited my question to show some more code. `logMessage` is not called repeatedly, and I don't care much if the logging works, hence the `next(null, {})`

Comment: Where does `message` come from?

Comment: @Ryan `var message = new PublicMessage();` with the latter being a `mongoose` model: `PublicMessage = this.server.mongoose.model('PublicMessage');` and `PublicMessage` imported from another file.

Comment: Oh, it might be a property thing. Are you on a version of Node that supports object spread? Does `data: {...message}` work? (If on an older version: `data: Object.assign({}, message)`)

Comment: @Ryan I've tried, but neither of them worked. They both throw the `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

Comment: Yeah, ajax-request might be doing some strange serialization and reading some unintended Mongoose property.

Answer (score 1):

The `ajax-request` module is likely failing at serializing the object. You do realize that `message` is not sent as an object, it has to be converted to a string format to be sent. Also I am not sure that it's possible to serialize that data as there is no form input that can have nested names.

You can try using a more tested module like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or just use JSON.

Comment: Fair enough, but why is, for example, `data: { id: message["sender"]["id"], name: message["sender"]["name"], email: message["sender"]["email"] }` working just fine? The whole thing is an object not a string, and that object is the same as `message[sender]`.

Comment: That's probably because the module `ajax-request` is not programmed to handle it gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bad workaround, but at least it works, so I put it as an answer in the hope it might help someone else as well:

```
data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(message))
```

I simply convert the `message` object to a string and parse it back to a Json object. No idea why that works.